# imageView centered inside scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uistoryboard

How can I vertically center an image inside a scrollView?

I'm using storyboards in Xcode 5. The main view is embedded inside a navigation controller, and "Adjust scroll view insets" option is enabled in main Storyboard. This main view has a scrollView which size is equal to the main view size.

The imageView is inside the scrollView and it's the same size as the scrollView. Content mode is set to AspectFit.

So, hierarchy is as follows:

```
- UINavigationController
- UIView
   - UIScrollView
       - UIImageView
```

The image may be landscape or portrait, and can be any size (it's loaded at runtime). This is why imageView is the same size as the scrollView.

How can I vertically center the image inside the scrollView?

**EDIT:**
As commented before, I have set imageView's contentMode to AspectFit because the image may be too big, so I need it resized. The problem I have is that the image is not center of the scrollView.

You can check screenshot at [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/images/screenshot.png) and download source code at [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/downloads/ImageCenteredOnScrollView.zip).

Comment: If you select the uiimageview, you can set its constraints, if you are using autolayout. Set the width and the height, because it seems you want that constant. Then set horizontal and vertical in container.

Comment: I can't set constrains to imageView because I don't know the image size until runtime (image will be downloaded... may be landscape or portrait... maybe it'll be bigger than screen size or maybe smaller). Any other idea? I have uploaded the code. Link can be found in the original post. Thx!

Comment: But you took care of setting the picture to fill up the most it can by setting the content mode.  Do you need to always see the entire picture?  Try my method out, the picture stays centered and you see the entire thing.  Even if you switch the pictures.  I like how you commented the one out so you can switch back and forth, I do that all the time!!

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer to deal with pinch zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be good to use auto layout as mentioned by @Douglas. However, if you prefer the traditional way, you can also make it work.

I'll first give you the answer and then explain it to you. You should first delete the image view from the storyboard ( I'll explain it later), and then add the `viewWillAppear` method.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // 1. Add the image view programatically
        UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait.jpg"]];
        [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        _imageView = imageView;

    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        // 2. calculate the size of the image view
        CGFloat scrollViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(_scrollView.frame);
        CGFloat scrollViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(_scrollView.frame);
        CGFloat imageViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(_imageView.frame);
        CGFloat imageViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(_imageView.frame);
        CGFloat widthRatio = scrollViewWidth / imageViewWidth;
        CGFloat heightRation = scrollViewHeight / imageViewHeight;
        CGFloat ratio = MIN(widthRatio, heightRation);
        CGRect newImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageViewWidth * ratio, imageViewHeight * ratio);
        _imageView.frame = newImageFrame;

        // 3. find the position of the imageView.
        CGFloat scrollViewCenterX = CGRectGetMidX(_scrollView.bounds);
        CGFloat scrollViewCenterY = CGRectGetMidY(_scrollView.bounds) + _scrollView.contentInset.top / 2 ;
        _imageView.center = CGPointMake(scrollViewCenterX, scrollViewCenterY);
    }
```

Here is the explanation:

1. You should not put the imageView in the storyboard, otherwise the frame of the imageView will be fixed by the storyboard, and will not change with the size of the image. Even if you choose `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, the frame of the imageView is still not changed. It just add some white space around the image.
2. Now the imageView has the same size as your image. If you want it to be fully displayed, you need to calculate the frame yourself.
3. Pay attention to the `_scrollView.contentInset.top / 2`, this is why you need to put the codes in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. The `_scrollView.contentInset.top` is the height of the navigation bar and is calculated automatically for you before `willViewAppear`.

You put your image view in a scrollView, I guess you want to zoom in and out. If this is true, add `self.imageView = imageView;` and the bottom of `viewDidLoad`. Set the delegate of `_scrollView` to `self` and add the following method:

```
    - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        return _imageView;
    }
```

Comment: Thx! I'll give it a try and I'll let you know soon :)

Comment: You were right, it's necessary to init and add the imageView on viewDidLoad call (`self.imageView = [[self.imageView alloc] init]`) then `[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView]`), otherwise imageView's position will be fixed because of the storyboard. Then calculate center as you suggested. One thing though is that `scrollView.contentInset.top` is being calculated on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, just right before `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

I made a comment, but then took a look at your project.  You are almost there.  I ran through the following steps and have gotten the result you are looking for.

First, make sure you have auto layout turned ON!!!

In your storyboard click on your scroll view.  You had a scroll view that was the same size as the view.  You are going to put on some constraints.  Down at the bottom of the story board you will see some icons.

[image]

The fourth one over looks sort of like an I-beam on its side, it is the pin button.  After selecting the scroll view, click on this and it will bring up a pop up menu.

[image]

For the scroll view click on all the bars around the middle block so you pin the scroll view to the sides of the main view.

[image]

You will notice they are all red now.

Then go and click on the imageview.  Once again you had it set to the size of the view.  Using the pin button again, you are going to pin just the Width at 320 and the Height at 568.  When you are done you are then going to use the next button over.

[image]

This is the align button.  Click on that after you have selected your image view.  You are going to click on Horizontal Center in Container, and Vertical Center in Container.

Next you will need to add one method to your ViewController.m file.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Start up the simulator and let her rip!  You will get one warning though.  It says the content size is ambiguous for the scroll view.  But that's OK, because you will set it on viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Hope that helps, or helps someone out.  Autolayout and scroll views are a bit tough!!

EDIT#1

if you want to then make the image view scalable, by pinch zooming you can do the following.

Make sure you made the .h file follow the UIScrollViewDelagate.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

This will allow the scroll view to be able to access the delegate methods of the scroll view.  The method you are looking for is called..

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

Then in the viewDidLoad method of your .m file do the following.

```
_scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
_scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
_scrollView.delegate = self;
```

The underscore and the variable name is the same as self.variable.  Either will work.

That should do it.  Let me know if it works or if you have any other questions.  ENJOY!

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I realised that if I don't pin imageView's width and height then I don't get the warning related to "ambiguity" issues. Furthermore, I didn't have to set content size in viewDidLayoutSubviews. But there is a caveat, adding these constraints will stop zoom-in functionality with scrollView, which is the purpose of using a scrollView in this project. As for this question (centering image in scrollview) I think your answers is OK, but remains the zooming issue :(

Comment: I will look into that. I use zooming in one if my apps so we should be able to figure it out!

Comment: Thx Douglas. Regarding zooming issue I meant that I already have zooming. It works if don't set vertical and horizontal constraints to imageView. But when I do, there is some weird behaviour when zooming-in... I have updated project files here [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/downloads/ImageCenteredOnScrollView.zip)

Comment: Will take a look at that as well.  Get back to you soon.  Downloading new project now.

Comment: @AJGM, what are you trying to accomplish with the code you added?  Just so I know what you want, thanks.

Comment: (1) center image inside scrollview (2) zoom-in/out image while keeping the image at the center once image has been zoom-out

Comment: Thx Douglas! @森森最爱MIKU傲娇的双马尾 approach allow me to zoom without problems since it's not using any constraints in storyboards. I think there should be a way of doing this by means of storyboards, but I haven't been able to get it work.

Comment: Besides the one warning that my sample gives you, and we take care of it at runtime.  The image stays in the center on rotation and pinch zooming.  And it was done totally on the storyboard.  Hope you finish the app!

Comment: Didn't you get some weird behaviour when zoomin-in? That's the only disadvantage I found when doing it through storyboards.

Comment: None at all. Always centered with rotation and zoom.

Comment: :o How did you do that? In my project I couldn't get it done :( only by following @Sen comments

Comment: Just followed my instructions.  How did you load the project to the web.  Perhaps I can load up mine so you can see.

Comment: Why not turning this: [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; into this: [scrollView.contentSize = self.view.frame.size];

Comment: Obviously without the brackets :P it's much more OOP and it's almost natural language "make my scrollview content size equal to my view size"

Comment: @PedroBorges, just personal preference, but yes, both would work!!

Comment: Doesn't your scrollview scroll through the black edges of an imageView rendered in AspectFit mode? Because that's the tricky part, avoiding that!

Comment: @PedroBorges, no it does not, looks pretty normal to me.

Answer (score 0):

These are the ones u can use, the 3 modes of ImageView content display.You can do this by dynamically setting them or u can set them in storyboard too, click on the ImageView and go to properties tab-bar and choose from there, run them and select which output u want.

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Same as with @sargeras... I have set contentMode to AspectFit. This way, I get the image resized to fit imageView. The problem is that this image is not being center within scrollView. You can check screenshot at [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/images/screenshot.png) and download source code at [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/downloads/ImageCenteredOnScrollView.zip).

Comment: is your UIView set in the position of the scrollView that u want it to be? ie center?

Comment: yes, it's in the center. You can download this project from here [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/downloads/ImageCenteredOnScrollView.zip)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center image in an imageview use

```
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

image retains it's size in this this content mode. Alternatively you can use other content modes as per your requirement.

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.
UIViewContentModeRedraw,              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)
UIViewContentModeCenter,              // contents remain same size. positioned adjusted.
UIViewContentModeTop,
UIViewContentModeBottom,
UIViewContentModeLeft,
UIViewContentModeRight,
UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
UIViewContentModeTopRight,
UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
```

Comment: If I use UIViewContentModeCenter then the image won't be resized to fit into the imageView. That's why I set contentMode to AspectFit. The problem is that the image is not being center within scrollView.

Comment: You can check screenshot at [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/images/screenshot.png) and download source code at [link](http://www.ajgm.mx/downloads/ImageCenteredOnScrollView.zip).